# Is there an Android API for getting a localized version of a file size?

Tags: android, localization

In Android I want to display a file size to the user and I want to localize it.

So if I have the size 5.4 MB it should be shown as "5.4 MB" in English, "5,4 MB" in Swedish, "5,4 Mo." in French and an appropriate version in Arabic with [Eastern Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) and the MB part in Arabic.

I can get the numerals and decimal separator correct using [String.format()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) or [DecimalFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) as mentioned in the [Android Localization Checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html#design) document.

But what should I do about the file size unit (B, kB, MB, etc)? Is there some pattern for stringFormat that I'm missing or something else that can be used to get the correct localized form of this?

On iOS the class [NSByteCountFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSByteCountFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) seems to be available for this purpose, is there something similar on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [the static `formatFileSize()` method on the `Formatter` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter.html#formatFileSize%28android.content.Context,%20long%29).

Comment: Great, thanks that was exactly what I needed. Not sure why I couldn't find it when searching before. The name is so obvious.

Comment: starting from Oreo isn't good solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66019926/android-text-format-formatter-formatfilesize-returns-wrong-format