# android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize() returns wrong format

Tags: android

Here I compare Android built-in method to format file and custom from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5599842/7767664

```
Timber.d(
    "Format file size using Formatter.formatFileSize " +
            "${Formatter.formatFileSize(this, 1_000_000_000L)}, " +
            "${Formatter.formatFileSize(this, 1_073_741_824L)}"
)

Timber.d(
    "Format file size using readableFileSize " +
            "${readableFileSize(1_000_000_000L)}, " +
            "${readableFileSize(1_073_741_824L)}"
)
```

.

```
fun readableFileSize(size: Long): String? {
    if (size <= 0) return "0"
    val units = arrayOf("B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB")
    val digitGroups = (log10(size.toDouble()) / log10(1024.0)).toInt()
    return DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / 1024.0.pow(digitGroups.toDouble()))
        .toString() + " " + units[digitGroups]
}
```

Here's the result:

```
Format file size using Formatter.formatFileSize 1,00 GB, 1,07 GB
Format file size using readableFileSize 953,7 MB, 1 GB
```

What is wrong with `android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize`?

**UPDATE**

starting from Oreo Android it uses 1000 instead of 1024 bytes for 1 kb

[image]

we could use `Formatter.formatFileSize(this, 1024L, Formatter.FLAG_IEC_UNITS)`

but method with third parameter is hidden in source code:

```
/** @hide */
public static String formatFileSize(@Nullable Context context, long sizeBytes, int flags) {
    if (context == null) {
        return "";
    }
    final BytesResult res = formatBytes(context.getResources(), sizeBytes, flags);
    return bidiWrap(context, context.getString(com.android.internal.R.string.fileSizeSuffix,
            res.value, res.units));
}
```

so it seems there is no built-in method to get normally formatted localized file size for newer Android version anymore